# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

Stuck with this error...

```
DECLARE
 AVGRUNTIME                            number(10,0);
 PERFCATEGORYRANGELOCOUNT              number(10,0);
 PERFCATEGORYRANGEHICOUNT              number(10,0);
 DW_LOW                                number(10,0);
 DW_HI                                 number(10,0);     

CURSOR LC_ABC IS

select distinct(ap.dwprocessid) 
from auditprocess ap, dwprocess d
where ap.dwprocessid = d.dwprocessid
and ap.insertts > sysdate - 61
and dwprocessmonitorind = 'Y';

BEGIN

FOR REC IN LC_ABC
LOOP

select ((ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS)*24*60*60) as AVGRUNTIME,
(.1 * ((ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS)))as PERFCATEGORYRANGELOCOUNT ,
(1.9 * ((ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS)))as PERFCATEGORYRANGEHICOUNT
INTO AVGRUNTIME, PERFCATEGORYRANGELOCOUNT, PERFCATEGORYRANGEHICOUNT
from auditprocess ap
where ap.dwprocessid = rec.dwprocessid 
and insertts > sysdate - 61
group by (ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS);
```

[Error][1] at line 1
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 27

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - your query on `auditprocess` returns more than one row, but you are trying to enter the row values into single-valued variables. In addition: you are selecting from `ap` but in the WHERE clause you also reference `rec`. This should give you an error before the one you showed; so... are you sure what you posted is your EXACT code? I tend to not believe it.

Comment: @mathguy rec is the record from cursor in for loop. He have to set alias for distinct() as dwprocessid  . For the other you have right.

Comment: @mathguy rec is from the cursor

Comment: lol meblind, you guys are obviously right and I obviously not!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by  `ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS` and if you have 2 different values an error will rise since you cannot insert 2 rows into a variable.
Maybe you should not group by those columns and use an aggregation function on the select clause like:

```
select avg((ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS)*24*60*60) as AVGRUNTIME,
       min(.1 * ((ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS)))as PERFCATEGORYRANGELOCOUNT ,
       max(1.9 * ((ap.LASTUPDATETS - INSERTTS)))as PERFCATEGORYRANGEHICOUNT
INTO AVGRUNTIME, PERFCATEGORYRANGELOCOUNT, PERFCATEGORYRANGEHICOUNT
from auditprocess ap
where ap.dwprocessid = rec.dwprocessid 
and insertts > sysdate - 61;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the error says.  Your SELECT...INTO returns more than one row.

CURSOR LC_ABC contains a DISTINCT - this implies you already know that dwProcessId may occur more than once in table auditProcess.

Then you select again from the table using the exact same logic - this will return all matching rows.

You then aggregate using the value of lastUpdateTS - insertTs.  You will therefore return one row per dwProcessId per value of (lastUpdateTS - insertTs)